# How to use Ghostscript command to validate all pdfs in a folder

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I wish to validate pdfs in a Windows 7 folder containing 30,000 pdfs. I have discovered that some pdfs do not render properly and give a "Insufficient data for image" error.

How can I modify following Ghostscript command to input all pdfs in a folder, rather than as a single pdf or a list of pdfs?

gswin32c.exe -o nul -sDEVICE=nullpage -r36x36 "D:/Pdf/04701.pdf"

Answer (score 1):

OK first, Ghostscript doesn't 'validate' PDFs, all your command line does is determine whether the **default** behaviour of Ghostscript, while interpreting a file, sends any messages to stdout or stderr.

There are several problems with that, Ghostscript doesn't flag even a warning for everything, and the default behaviour is not to throw an error, but to emit a warning and continue. Since you aren't looking at the output (its going to a bit bucket) its entirely possible that you would miss the fact that swathes of output were simply blank. SO you may well miss a faulty file.

'Insufficient data for an image' is simply one possible error, there are an awful lot of badly written PDF files out there.

If you want to handle every file in a folder, you can't do it with Ghostscript alone, as it requires each input file to be specified. However, you can write a command shell script easily enough. Since you are clearly on Windows, just use a for loop and have the 'do' clause call Ghostscript just as above.

Something like:

```
For %s in (c:\files\*.*) do gswin32c... %s
```

just type

> help for

at the command shell for information on 'for'.